# Returning the value of a block over an Enumeration when not nil

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have a bit of an odd use-case for a Ruby Enumerable, it seems. I am attempting to do something like the following:

```
result = my_strategies.some_method do |strategy|
    strategy.get_result
end
```

The method **some_method** is just a placeholder, but is the basis behind the rest of this question.

The enumerable my_strategies contains an ordered list of strategies for retrieving a value from a remote service; a more preferable strategy is run before a less preferable strategy,

Sometimes the more preferable strategy will fail, in a way that retries alone won't correct. In that case, the strategy will return nil.

I can see a way of doing this by relying on an each block, thusly:

```
result = nil

my_strategies.each do |strategy|
    result = strategy.get_result
    if not r.nil?
        break
    end
end
```

This seems unnecessarily noisy. I'm wondering if there is a method I can substitute **some_method** for in my first example; something similar to .any?, but returning the value that caused the block to be true, instead of just returning true.

Alternate approaches to what I am trying to do are also welcome.

**EDIT:** I originally asked this question because I had tried this block of code:

```
result = my_strategies.find do |strategy|
    strategy.get_result
end
```

Except that this returned me the strategy that succeeded, instead of the value it returned when it did. I don't care about which strategy got me the value, I just want to know what the value is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your need is very common but unfortunately there is no such abstraction in the core. However, [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) guys identified this gap a long time ago and implemented [Enumerable#find_yield](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#find_yield-instance_method) (a.k.a [Enumerable#map_detect](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms#Enumerable#map_detect)):

```
result = my_strategies.map_detect { |strategy| strategy.get_result }
```

Or simply: `result = my_strategies.map_detect(&:get_result)`. Ruby 2.0 implements lazy enumerables (for early versions use [enumerable-lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy)) so now we can write:

```
result = my_strategies.lazy.map(&:get_result).reject(&:nil?).first
```

Comment: Yes. This is sort of the pattern I found myself implementing. What I was wondering is if there is is already an implementation of this somewhere; I want to avoid writing my own version of existing functionality.

Comment: @Ed: no, there is no such abstraction, I'll edit the answer to add some references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to iterate through the array until you get your result:

```
result = nil

my_strategies.find do |strategy|
    result = strategy.get_result
end
```

Comment: Actually, now that I stumbled on `Enumerable#find` this is much better!

Comment: see my edit. This gives me something different than what I am wanting returned, unless I am misunderstanding the semantics of find.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the OP wants the output of get_result, not the strategy itself.

Comment: Oh shoot. For some reason I misread the docs... Assigning within the closure should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to doing this (without using a block):

```
result = nil
num = 0

while result.nil?
  result = my_strategies[num].get_result
  num += 1
end
```